# Definition of the multiplicity of an analytic coherent sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

In algebraic geometry, for a coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on a variety $X$ and an irreducible component $Z$ of $\mathrm{supp}(\mathcal{F})$, the **multiplicity** of $\mathcal{F}$ in $Z$ is 
$$
\mathrm{Length}_{\mathcal{O}_{X,\xi}}\mathcal{F}_\xi,
$$
where $\mathcal{O}_X$ is the structure sheaf of $X$ and $\xi$ is the generic point of $Z$.

My question is: 
**what is the analogous notion in the context of complex analytic geometry?**

More precisely, for a coherent analytic sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on a complex analytic space $X$ and an analytic irreducible component $Z$ of $\mathrm{supp}(\mathcal{F})$, *what is the multiplicity of $\mathcal{F}$ in $Z$?*